# Angularjs multiplication operation in html

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using http get request to get data and show it in my directive, gauge directive has value attribute that takes number, i am binding like this value="" attribute from ng-repeat in html. The problem is the value i'm getting from get request is in decimal like 0.23 etc but i need to multiply this value with 100 to show it in percentage, is it possible in angularjs to do something like this.
I tried like

```
<div id="main" ng-repeat="n in myObject">

<gage name="name" id="myGage-n.id" value=n.myValuex100>

</div>
```

But when i check in developer toolbar the value attribute shows value=n.myValuex100 as is. It's not replacing it with the multiplied value , in this case expected value is "23"

Please suggest if i'm missing something or need to do in a different way

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use your multiplication formula in {{}} expression

**For example 1**

```
{{5*5}}
```

**For example 2**

```
{{number*5}}
```

Refer following example

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.number = 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">  
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, multiplication is {{5*5}} ! <br>
  Hello, multiplication is {{number*5}} !
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Since this is a JustGage plugin(http://justgage.com/)  which is converted into directive it takes value without curly braces so that's why i'm using w/o curly braces

Answer (score 0):

Actually w/o {{}} and "" worked for me. 
Like this